# $\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n^5}}$ test for convergence

Tags: calculus

Let $\sum a_{n}=\sum \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n^5}}$. To find if the serie is convergence or not, I had some difficult on finding the proper serie to test the given one.

After some work around, I found this sequence $b_{n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^3}}$, whose serie converges!

Then I applyed the limit test comparasion.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n^5}}\cdot \sqrt{n^3}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{\sqrt{n^{2}}}=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{n}=0$$

If the limit is equal $0$ and the $\sum b_{n}$ converges, then $\sum a_{n}$ converges to.

My main difficult was to fint out the proper $b_{n}$. Is there an easy way to find it? Thanks

Comment: The bottom is $n^{5/2}$. "Borrow" enough from $5/2$ to kill the $\log$, leaving enough (more than $1$) for convergence. Any borrowing $e$, where $0\lt e\lt 1.5$ will do the job. You chose $e=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have in your repository that exponential functions grow faster than any power - and conversely logarithms grow slower than any power, including fractionals powers. That is, $\ln n <\sqrt n$ for sufficiently big $n$. This leaves you simply with $\frac 1{n^2}$ (or even $\frac1{n^{5/2-\epsilon}}$ for any positive $\epsilon$).

Answer (score 0):

Once you know that
$\ln(n)/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$,
by putting $n = m^a$
for any real $a > 0$,
you get
$\ln(m)/m^a \to 0$
as $m \to \infty$.